# Intellij Maven says Dependency not found but the same is working in eclipse

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I wanted to use Intellij to code but the issue is it is not recognizing one dependency but the same does not happen in Eclipse. Attached is the error I am getting.

[Maven error Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE38r.png)
I tried the following things but none of them worked.

1. Maven reload all projects
2. Invalidate Cache
3. Maven Settings checked Always update snapshots
4. Maven clean and Install

Can someone guide me on this with what is the exact issue? Because it does not show any such error in eclipse. Why Intellij has this issue?

Comment: Which IntelliJ version do you use?

Comment: 2022.2.3 is the Intellij version I use.

Comment: First upgrade your version to most recent 2022.3.1 ... also close the project in intellij ... delete `.idea` directory ... and import the project from scratch...

Comment: It could be a configuration issue in the settings.xml file for the maven project. Try searching for settings.xml for IJ and Ecplise and compare them.

Comment: Settings .xml isn't there for eclipse or I was not able to found. Also I cleared the .idea file but no success.

Comment: Do you have proxies in network? Does maven clean install work from the command line? Make sure you use the same settings.xml in IDE (`~/.m2/` directory by default) and in the command line.

Comment: Maven clean install does not work through the command line. It gives the same dependency not found error.